# How to compute image mean for a set of image files?

Tags: cntk

Does anyone have a high level explanation on how to compute the image mean for a set of images (.jpg files in a folder) and generate a XML-file in the correct format for the ImageDeserializer?

I have seen the code in the CNTK_201A_CIFAR-10_DataLoader, which does this. But, the input there is in a different format, so it's unclear exactly how to deal with this for the image files as input.

Answer (score 2):

You can just follow the code sample that [computes the mean input for CIFAR](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/v2.0.beta7.0/Examples/Image/DataSets/CIFAR-10/cifar_utils.py#L101). Basically it goes through all the training images and computes the average. Then it writes it in a file in a format that OpenCV will understand. The first part is easy because of numpy and PIL and the second part is easy because of minidom.

Comment: Could you go a little bit more into detail? As I said, I have looked at the code referenced in the link provided. However the mean calculation is kind of convoluted into the saveImage function. The source format in the CIFAR case seems to be a text file that is different from what you get if you read a .jpg file with PIL. I think the Tutorial would be a bit cleaner if the mean had been calculated based on the finished file images, or if it was clear exactly what format the mean calculation was performed on.

Comment: Inside the saveImage function in the CNTK_201A_CIFAR-10_DataLoader it looks like mean is computed, then there are some steps of code that is not very obvious. It looks like some padding is done. Will this not affect the correctness of the mean calculation, since it looks like the mean is calculated on a different image? Then there are a couple of nested for loops with no comments. It would help if the function logic was explained a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a complete solution, based on the links that Nikos provided, for computing the mean from all images stored in a ZIP files (if you are using the ZIP image reader) or from a list of image files.

Regarding your questions: In the DataLoader tutorial, padding only affects the codepath for saving the images to file, not for computing the mean.

```py
import zipfile
import io
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from scipy.misc import imread, imresize, fromimage
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
import xml.dom.minidom
# saveMean function taken from 
# https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/v2.0.beta7.0/Examples/Image/DataSets/CIFAR-10/cifar_utils.py#L84
def saveMean(fname, data, imgSize):
    root = et.Element('opencv_storage')
    et.SubElement(root, 'Channel').text = '3'
    et.SubElement(root, 'Row').text = str(imgSize)
    et.SubElement(root, 'Col').text = str(imgSize)
    meanImg = et.SubElement(root, 'MeanImg', type_id='opencv-matrix')
    et.SubElement(meanImg, 'rows').text = '1'
    et.SubElement(meanImg, 'cols').text = str(imgSize * imgSize * 3)
    et.SubElement(meanImg, 'dt').text = 'f'
    et.SubElement(meanImg, 'data').text = ' '.join(['%e' % n for n in np.reshape(data, (imgSize * imgSize * 3))])
    tree = et.ElementTree(root)
    tree.write(fname)
    x = xml.dom.minidom.parse(fname)
    with open(fname, 'w') as f:
        f.write(x.toprettyxml(indent = '  '))
def loadAndResize(f, networkSize):
    im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(f))
    n = fromimage(im).astype(np.float)
    return imresize(n, (networkSize, networkSize))
```

Then use these building blocks in functions that either reads images as bytes from a ZIP file, or from the raw files:

```py
def meanFromZip(zipFile, networkSize):
    imgSum = np.zeros((networkSize, networkSize, 3), np.float)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zipFile) as z:
        allFiles = z.namelist()
        for f in allFiles:
            imgSum = imgSum + loadAndResize(z.read(f), networkSize)
    return imgSum / len(allFiles)
def meanFromFiles(files, networkSize):
    imgSum = np.zeros((networkSize, networkSize, 3), np.float)
    for f in files:
        with open(f, 'rb') as b:
            imgSum = imgSum + loadAndResize(b.read(), networkSize)
    return imgSum / len(files)
```

Invoke as follows:

```py
zipFile = "myImages.zip"
networkSize = 224
mean = meanFromZip(zipFile, networkSize)
saveMean("mean.xml", mean, networkSize)
files = ["c:/temp/Column0_Line16.jpg", "C:/temp/Column0_Line47.jpg"]
mean2 = meanFromFiles(files, networkSize)
```

Comment: "Regarding your questions: In the DataLoader tutorial, padding only affects the codepath for saving the images to file, not for computing the mean.": Yes, but shouldn't the mean be calculated on basis of what is saved to file? It is the files that is input to the training and I would have thought that the mean file is supposed to reflect the content of the actual files created and not be calculated on the input.

Comment: I have tried to use your code to generate the mean XML file, but I can't get it to be identical to the XML file provided as a part of the CIFAR tutorial. The XML file provided is computed based on the 32x32x3 pixel input images. The generated .png files are 40x40x3 pixels, so it would be rather impossible to generate the mean on those and have it to be identical to the mean calculated on the 32x32x3 images. I think that there may be a flaw in the tutorial here.